# Unable to import tensorflow lite image classifier

Tags: tensorflow

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification

I am running through the tensorflow lite example and get an import error when trying to import image classifier.

```
pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git#egg=tensorflow-examples[model_maker]


from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_maker.core.task import image_classifier


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official.nlp'
```

Comment: Did you have cloned the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clone the repo, and then use this path:

```
PYTHONPATH=path\to\models
```

Be careful with the python path you'll be using.

[Github repo redirect](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker)

Comment: Yes thanks i just got it working, my path was messed up it was importing official from somewhere else.